# How to print to a fax?

Tags: windows-7, printing, fax

I'd like to know if I can "print" from Windows 7 to a fax?  The fax is not connected to the computer: it is located in another country and all I've got is the fax number.

I remember it's old technology but I've got a use case where my father-in-law asks me to send a document to a friend's fax.

Any solution is welcome: basically it's been 15 years I've not used a fax, at least and I've no idea how to send something to a fax. I don't know if I need a paid service, I don't know what's involved. So I figure out some superuser might be able to help.

Comment: A: "Can you sent me a fax?"
B: "No, I can not due that due to where I live."
A: "Oh, where is that?"
B: "In the 21st century". :)

Comment: But seriously, you need two three things: 1) a phone line (possible a landline). 2) A classic modem.  3) Some software.  I have no experience with part 3 so I am not pposting an answer, but unless you get the phone/modem parts covered it is not going to work.

Comment: the best way is to use a service like efax.com others are listed here: http://www.tomsguide.com/us/best-online-fax,review-2124.html

Comment: Printing to a fax machine is basically what a fax is (except the print quality sucks compared to anything you would use as a normal printer).  You do it by sending a fax to that phone number.  The document must be converted into the correct format/encoding for output on the fax machine.  There is software (in fact, Windows 7 may include it, possibly as a "printer"), that you use like a printer driver.  It outputs the fax-ready copy and dials the number on your built-in phoneline modem if your computer is old enough to include one.

Comment: You can get a faxmodem card that plugs in to an available slot or a USB faxmodem.  (I used to have a card but now have a USB faxmodem after losing the slot to a video card.)  It will come with the available software and plugs in to your landline (assuming you have one), which is, obviously, a requirement.  From there you just open the document you want to fax and print it.  The faxmodem will be an available device.

Comment: If you're in the US, I believe you can see a real faxmodem at the Smithsonian, in an exhibit next to the dinosaur bones.  :-)

Comment: Win7 has Windows Fax and Scan (can be enabled via Windows Features), but as others have noted you'll need a modem and an ISD phone connection. Isn't there any place you can go to (such as an office) that has an actual fax machine? Better still, why isn't emailing a HQ scan that can be printed at the other end a viable option?

Comment: Using a faxmodem you can print to a fax .. There are few fax programs that will let you fax and receive documents. Go for Sam Leffler's HylaFAX. It supports all sorts of things from multiple modems to broadcasting.